# Is it possible to have an ObjectProvider providing objects from other packages?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

## Initial situation

I'm currently building an API with Spring using the library [PipelinR](https://github.com/sizovs/PipelinR), which is inspired by the famous NuGet package [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR). I've created multiple packages within this application to isolate the java classes. The entrypoint of the API is in the package `com.example.project.WebApi`. The configuration file for the pipeline is also located here.

```
@Configuration
public class PipelinrConfiguration {

    @Bean
    Pipeline pipeline(ObjectProvider<Command.Handler> commandHandlers, ObjectProvider<Notification.Handler> notificationHandlers, ObjectProvider<Command.Middleware> middlewares) {
        return new Pipelinr()
          .with(commandHandlers::stream)
          .with(notificationHandlers::stream)
          .with(middlewares::orderedStream);
    }
    
}
```

Anyways all the commands and command handlers are in different packages, like `com.example.project.ApplicationService.CreateSomethingCommand`.

```
com.example.project.ApplicationService.CreateSomething/
    CreateSomethingCommand.java
    CreateSomethingCommandHandler.java
```

Does anybody knows how I could provide these classes in my `PipelinrConfiguration.java` file, so that the ObjectProvider is able to find those.

I highly appreciate any kind of help, cheers!

---

## Edit: #001

Yes, the beans are annotated with `@Component`.

`CreateSomethingCommand.java`

```
public class CreateSomethingCommand implements Command<Voidy> {

    public String host;
    
    public CreateSomethingCommand() {
        
    }
    
    public CreateSomethingCommand(String host) {
        this();
        this.host = host;
    }
    
}
```

`CreateSomethingCommandHandler.java`

```
@Component
public class CreateSomethingCommandHandler implements Command.Handler<CreateSomethingCommand, Voidy> {

    @Override
    public Voidy handle(CreateSomethingCommand command) {
        
        System.out.println("Command recieved by " + command.host);
        
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are those beans annotated in the package (like `@Component`)? In this case you can use `@ComponentScan`. If the beans are not annotated you can declare the `@Bean` In your `@Configuration` class. If this is the case just be sure to give a name to the different `ObjectProvider` beans and use `@Qualifier` to inject the correct ones

Comment: @Pp88 Thanks for your answer. I've edited my question with more detaisl. Anyways you are right. The beans are annotated with `@Component`. May it possible for you to provide an example on how to use `@ComponentScan`?

Comment: @Pp88 No need to give an example anymore. This is the perfect soltuion for my problem! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"package1”, "package2"})
public class PipelinrConfiguration {
    // attention here you have to declare three different beans of type ObjectProvider otherwise it will inject by type
    @Bean
    Pipeline pipeline(@Qualifier(“bean1”) ObjectProvider<Command.Handler> commandHandlers, @Qualifier(“bean2”)  ObjectProvider<Notification.Handler> notificationHandlers, @Qualifier(“bean3”) ObjectProvider<Command.Middleware> middlewares) {
        return new Pipelinr()
          .with(commandHandlers::stream)
          .with(notificationHandlers::stream)
          .with(middlewares::orderedStream);
    }
    
}
```